# How do I get the other two starter pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

In Pokemon Red Version, you are allowed to choose one out of the 3 starter Pokemon. Well, I chose Charmander but now I am confused as to how I can catch the other 2 starter Pokemon. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Back when I played it when I was little we used to do it by transferring from other Pokemon games

Comment: Yeah but I don't have a cable -_-

Comment: You're going to have to have that to get the other two starters.

Comment: I re-tagged your question to conform to our standards; the pokemon tag is when you discuss the entire series, not a specific version, ala your shiny question.  And it's redundant to have the game name in the title; the tag already does that.  Please don't change it back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want everything legitimately, you'll need to trade with someone else, it's plain and simple.

It's the same for several other pokemon, which aren't available in Red but are in Blue (or yellow).

Some pokemon also evolve only during trading.

This is to encourage people buying the other game as well (and another gameboy) this is called [1 game for the price of 2](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneGameForThePriceOfTwo).

Comment: You don't have to trade, you can also use the Mew glitch. http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_glitch. See method #3 specifically.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the yellow version, you can get them all.  You start with a Pikachu, then through the game get given, win or find the other primary Pokemon: Charmander, Squirtle and Bulbasaur.  Like others have said if you didn't want to buy a new game, you'll have to trade with other people, or between your devices with your other games.

Unfortunately in red and blue you only get that one you choose.

Answer (score 0):

## Plug your game into Pokemon Stadium for the N64.

The game Pokemon Stadium for the Nintendo 64 included a plug-in attachment for the console's controllers that allowed you to plug a Pokemon Red or Blue Gameboy cartridge into it, so that you could take your Pokemon from your Gameboy game and use them to compete in the console game's tournaments.

Additionally, and most importantly for this answer, it allowed you to transfer your Pokemon from your Gameboy cartridge to your N64 cartridge for storage. While doing so, it was entirely possible to reset your Gameboy game and start over again, picking a different starting pokemon, evolving your one Eevee differently, picking the other fossil, and other similar decisions that lock you out of catching them all in a single playthrough.

Incidentally, one of the other options that Pokemon Stadium made available was allowing you to play the game saved on your Gameboy cartridge on a Gameboy emulator - and one of the commands available to you is to speed up the emulator's clock, letting you move around and move through battles much more quickly while you're replaying the game.

In later generations with access to Pokemon Home, you should be able to do something very similar with that service's pokemon storage, as well.

Answer (score -2):

**This only works in Pokemon Red/Blue.**

Actually, in Pokemon red/blue, you can legitimately catch all 3 starters. Just look in ur pokedex. Charmander/Charmeleon/Charizard u can catch in Cinnabar Island Pokemon Mansion (Charmander/Charmeleon fairly common and Charizard is very rare), the Squirtle family you can catch in Seafoam Islands (you have to walk in the cave not surf) and the Bulbasaur family you can catch at the Victory Road entrance area (probably in the grass, but idk for sure yet cuz I haven't gotten there yet, I've only caught Squirtle, charmeleon, and I have the Charizard I received from Prof. Oak as a Charmander. I will post an update on any information on where to catch the Bulbasaur family in the comments section of my answer. Red/blue/yellow are the only 3 Pokemon games where u can get all 3 starters without cheating.

Source: based on experience as I am doing a play through on my Pokemon red on my game boy color atm

Sources: experience

Comment: You might want to add an explanation of what exactly the difference is. Is it simply the japanese version or is this a fan-made fake ROM?